# Connecting python3 on Ubuntu to SQL Server 2014

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, ubuntu, pyodbc

I am trying to retrieve SQL data on a Linux Server (Ubuntu 16.04.2) in a Python 3.5 script using the ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server. Running the script on SQL Server and Python in windows goes fine. Running the script in Python in Linux throws a SQL Server Syntax error:

pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '0x107c'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

As I add or remove columns it changes '0x107c' to a different character suggesting that it is not a single illegal character, but several. With a more limited amount of columns the script even runs (excluded [Order Type text] and [Order Nr]).This leads me to suspect something goes wrong in character set conversion. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Python3.5:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

#Set parameters
sql_file = 'file.sql'

#Define methods
def SQLDataToDataframe(filename):
    fd = open('file.sql','r')
    content = fd.read()
    fd.close()
df = pd.read_sql(content, connection)
return df

#Import Data from SQL
connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'
                            'Server=Server;'
                            'Database=DB;'
                            'uid=User;pwd=Password')

 dataframe = SQLDataToDataframe(sql_file)
```

file.sql:

```
SELECT [ID]
  ,[Company Code]
  ,[Description]
  ,[Order Category]
  ,[Order Category Text]
  ,[Order Type]
  ,[Order Type text]
  ,[Order Nr]
FROM [TABLE]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for future reference. Don't use pyodbc on Linux to connect to MS SQL Server. Use pymssql instead. Instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pymssql/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pymssql-python-development.

Comment: I see the opposite recommendation from the same website. "There are several python SQL drivers available. However, Microsoft places its testing efforts and its confidence in pyodbc driver." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server

Comment: Hi Shoof, I am not sure about that. On Windows machines I always use pyodbc. However, for this purpose pymssql works better. Don't ask me why :)